# Searching public DNS for particular records

Tags: domain-name-system

I know it is possible to use a service such as mxtoolbox.com to query a domain for its records, e.g. MX and A.

Is it possible to do the reverse and search for all the domains that share the same record? For instance, example.com and example2.com both have an MX record pointing to mail.example3.com. Is there a way to search public DNS for mail.example3.com and get example.com and example2.com as results?

If it can't be done is it due to security/ privacy or a technological limitation of DNS?

Comment: moderators: why close?

Answer (score 1):

up to my knowledge there's no way of directly accessing such information. if you're someone like http://www.robtex.com/ or dns provider like [opendns](http://www.opendns.com/) or [googledns](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) over time you could gather and provide such information based on queries people make.

Comment: Yea, unless you have access to the TLD DNS boxes that run the internet chances are pretty slim.  There is no way to do this, better yet, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @BrentPabst Just curious ;)